# AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL when using googletest deathtest

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, googletest, address-sanitizer

I am using address sanitizers in conjunction with gtest. I have a test that which references a unique_ptr that is null and subsequently fails.

Edit: as pointed out in the comments, this ub. For simplicities sake, assume a nullcheck is present and raises a signal when the ptr ist null.

This is intended by the test and part of the design. My test contains the following line:

```
ASSERT_EXIT(..., ::testing::KilledBySignal(SIGSEGV),".*")
```

Without sanitizer, the test passes. With sanitizer, it fails, I get the following feedback from the sanitizer:

```
actual msg:
[  DEATH   ] AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
[  DEATH   ] =================================================================
[  DEATH   ] ==13242==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x55d0c75eb50f bp 0x7ffdd011b540 sp 0x7ffdd011b520 T0)
[  DEATH   ] ==13242==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
[  DEATH   ] ==13242==Hint: address points to the zero page.
```

This looks to me as if the sanitizer detects the SIGSEGV signal. The problem is: the signal is there by design and intended to be there. Is there a way to configure asan to ignore this?

Comment: First, accessing `nullptr` is not a way to generate SIGSEGV, it's a way to have some nasty Undefined Behaviour in the code. You should use [`std::raise`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/raise). Second, why is asan output a concern? You check for status signal and ignore the output in your assertion.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen the simple test program int main() { int * a = nullptr; *a = 2; } does indeed cause a segfault

Comment: It doesn't matter. Undefined Behaviour is undefined, compiler is allowed to optimise your program away entirely as soon as UB is encountered (as well as it's allowed to do absolutely anything else it wants). See [Undefined behavior can result in time travel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633)

Comment: Ub aside. Take any death Test that cause a sigsegv. Like using Std::raise. How to Adress the actual issue?

Comment: Well, that was my second point. Why is that an issue? Your `ASSERT_EXIT` accepts any message on death, so why do you care that asan prints its stuff?

Comment: With asan, the test fails. The output ist very important as it tells me why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This looks to me as if the sanitizer detects the SIGSEGV signal. The problem is: the signal is there by design and intended to be there.

That's not the problem. The problem is that *after* detecting the signal, the sanitizer runtime performs `exit(1)`, which causes the process to exit *differently*, and the `ASSERT_EXIT` detects that the child process did not in fact die with `SIGSEGV`.

> Is there a way to configure asan to ignore this?

Not really.

There is an `abort_on_error=1` which you could add to `ASAN_OPTIONS` environment variable, which will cause the child process to die with `SIGABRT`, but that still wouldn't satisfy your `ASSERT_EXIT`.

---

In general, `DEATH_TEST`s are rarely worth the paper they are written on, and certainly getting them to work under AddressSanitizer is pointless.

You can skip this test by compiling it conditionally (i.e. compile it *out* when `-fsanitize=address` is in effect). [Documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html#conditional-compilation-with-has-feature-address-sanitizer) on how to achieve that.